# Java - Converting a datetime into gregorian calender time(date)

Tags: java, datetime, google-data-api

I am using google data api which gives date in datetime format. I want to convert this DateTime format date in Gregorian calendar date format. Does anyone know any methods for doing this?

**Edited the question*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [class](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/DateTime.html) is definitely not Google's best work (I link to the API so I can confirm we are talking about the same class and version). Here is what I would do:

```
   public class DateTimeConverter extends DateTime {
         private DateTime originalTime;

         public DateTimeConverter(DateTime originalTime) {
              this.originalTime = originalTime;
         }

         public java.util.Date getDate() {
              return new java.util.Date(this.value);
         }
   }
```

Sample usage:

```
     DateTime originalTime;
     //Populate variable and then:
     java.util.Date myDate = new DateTimeConverter(originalTime).getDate();
```

From there you can make a Calendar. Dealing with what to do if the DateTime represents a Date only, and timezone issues, you can deal with from there (I don't know your requirements) but if you have to get serious about it, use JodaTime to handle this as much as possible.

Comment: interesting. I will try this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Also check this

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar getGregorianDate(Date date) {
        XMLGregorianCalendar xMLGregorianCalendar = null;
        try {
            GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
            c.setTime(date);
            xMLGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                    .newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return xMLGregorianCalendar;
    }

    public static Date getDate(XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar) {
        Date date = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
        return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

```
DateTime d = event.getEdited();

Date d = new Date(d.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a *learning test* I have created for one of mine application:

```
package learning;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.gdata.data.DateTime;

public class GDataDateTimeTest {

    @Test public void should_be_converted_to_gregorian_calendar() {
//      String[] timeZoneIDs = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
//      for (String timeZoneID : timeZoneIDs)
//          System.out.println(timeZoneID);

        Date startingDate = date("02 Jan 2013");
        String timeZoneID = "Europe/London";

        DateTime datetime = new DateTime(startingDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneID));

        // *** start conversion to a gregorian calendar:
        // we need to multiply the GData DateTime.tzShift * 60000 (the opposite of what you can find in the constructor used previously [search for the code])
        String[] availableTimeZoneIDsForOffset = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(datetime.getTzShift() *60000);
        // available timeZone IDs for the offset should contains our timeZoneID
        Assert.assertTrue(ArrayUtils.contains(availableTimeZoneIDsForOffset, timeZoneID));

        // then create a GregorianCalendar with one of the timeZone found for the timeZone offset
        // and set time in millis with GData DateTime.value
        String oneOfTheTimeZonesFoundBefore = availableTimeZoneIDsForOffset[0];
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(oneOfTheTimeZonesFoundBefore));
        cal.setTimeInMillis(datetime.getValue());
        Assert.assertEquals(startingDate.getTime(), cal.getTimeInMillis());
    }

    private Date date(String dateAsText) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").parse(dateAsText);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

I have added comments to help you find how to convert a `GData DateTime` using timezone offset too.